# How to send value to server based on user clicked in spinner item in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner in my activity which contain Operators name ,what I want when user selected item from spinner I want to send another value to server,like
if user select "Airtel" from spinner I have to send "AR" to server same like other items .how can I do that.

code:-\

```
<string-array name="operators">
    <item>Select Operator</item>
    <item>Aircel</item>
    <item>Airtel</item>
    <item>BSNL</item>
    <item>Idea</item>
    <item>Vodafone</item>
    <item>MTNL Delhi</item>
    <item>MTNL Mumbai</item>
</string-array>
```

here when user select item from above list I have to send value from below list according to above items.

```
 <string-array name="Operators_Code">
    <item>AC</item>
    <item>AT</item>
    <item>BS</item>
    <item>ID</item>
    <item>VD</item>
    <item>MT</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: what is the link between operators array and operators code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Spinner, similar to ListView, RecyclerView, etc., is an "adapter backed" View. That is, it gets the items to be displayed from an `Adapter`.

When you set the entries to be shown using `android:entries="@array/operators`, Spinner internally creates an Adapter with the supplied array items. This simple solution, however, doesn't support complex objects.

For your use case, you'll have to create a custom Adapter for your Spinner.

```
public class Operator {
    String name;
    String code;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

final List<Operator> operators = new ArrayList(7);
operators.add(new Operator("Select operator", null));
operators.add(new Operator("Aircel", "AC"));
operators.add(new Operator("Airtel", "AC"));
....
```

Next, set the adapter on your spinner:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> operatorsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, operators);
spinner.setAdapter(operatorsAdapter);
```

That's it. Now if you want to listen to user's selections, add a listener to your Spinner by:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final Operator selectedOperator = operatorsAdapter.getItem(position);
        final String selectedOperatorCode = selectedOperator.code;
        // TODO: Send the selected operator to the server.
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Comment: but I only send operator code to server based on item clicked

Comment: But when I write as you mentioned above as "Airtel,"aC" how it looks like in spinner like "Airtel","Ac" or "Airtel"

Comment: Oh I totally forgot about that. So `ArrayAdapter` will use the text returned by an item's `toString()` as an item's text in the Spinner.

Comment: one more thing can I add all the opearators name and code in one class and can acces in class

Comment: like operators.add()

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. Can you explain more?